# tikz: self loop with two arrows at the end (i.e. ending by ->>)

Tags: tikz-arrows

How to modify the following example to get a self loop labelled by "b" ENDING BY TWO ARROWS?
The other self loop labelled by "a" should remains as it is.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
  \node[initial,initial where=above,initial distance=4mm,accepting,state] (s) {s};
  \path
  (s)   edge     [loop right] node {$a$} (s)
        edge [->>,loop left] node {$b$} (s);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's best to include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), with all code in your preamble to help those that want to help you. Second, it seems (someone should correct me if I'm wrong here) that the `stealth'` arrow tip has been replaced by `Stealth[round]` in [Tikz 3.0](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), so that's what I employed. Here is the code, for the whole document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>={Stealth[round]},shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
  \node[initial,initial where=above,initial distance=4mm,accepting,state] (s) {s};
  \path
  (s)   edge [loop right] node {$a$} (s)
        edge [->,>={Stealth[flex,sep=-1pt,round] Stealth[round]},loop left] node {$b$} (s);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting picture:

[image]

Note that you can change the distance between the two tips by changing the `sep=-1pt` value to something smaller or bigger. Also, you can change `flex` to `bend` in the arrow tip option if you like how that looks better.